# How can I do this specific replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = input("Enter a string:")
character = input ("Enter a character:")
if character in string: #checks string to see if character is in it
    print ("Character found!")
else:
    print ("Character not found!")

blank = (" _ " * len(string))
print (blank)
```

I am making a hangman game and I am stuck at this part.

How can I make it so that when the person guesses a letter it replaces the specific " _ " for where the letter should be? Should I be using a for loop to go through all the " _ " 's and then use an if statement?

If someone could show me how it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method similar to the following to update your guess string each time the player guesses something.

```
def update_guesses(current_guess_string, key_string, character_guessed):
    out_string = ""
    for i in range(len(current_guess_string)):
        if current_guess_string[i] == "_" and key_string[i] == character_guessed):
            out_string += character_guessed
        else: out_string += current_guess_string[i]
    return out_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on your code, here's a set of changes that get you to a working game:

Set your string input to a fixed case and move your blank initialization to just after string input.  Change them both to lists so you can modify
them as needed:

```
# normalize case and convert to a mutable data structure
string = list(input("Enter a string: ").lower())

# the blank list matches the string except it starts all blanks
blank = list("_" * len(string))
```

Get a loop going for handling guesses.  Here I'm stopping the loop when the string list is all one character, presumably blanks, as we'll be swapping characters between the blank and input string lists:

```
while len(set(string)) > 1:  # when the string is all blanks, stop
```

Make sure to cleanup the user input to be only one character and change it to the same case as the string input:

```
    # normalize case on input and make sure to only get 1 character
    character = input("Enter a character: ").lower()[0]
```

After you test if the character is in the string, swap the character, by position, with a character in the blank string.  Do this in a loop so you get all instances of the guessed character:

```
     if character in string:  # checks string to see if character is in it
         print("Character found!")
         # find the character in the string and swap it with what's in
         # the blank string so we can handle multiple same characters
         # correctly
         while character in string:
            index = string.index(character)
            string[index] = blank[index]
            blank[index] = character

     else:
         print("Character not found!")
```

The last step in the main loop is to print the current state of the guesses:

```
     # print correct guesses and blanks
     print(*blank, sep='')
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply and sorry for the late reply, I have been very busy and I have some questions. What do you  mean by get a loop going for handling guesses? I apologise about this because I feel like what you say is very simple but my understanding of english isn't great  due to it being my 3rd language.

Comment: After initializing various things, the body of this program is a loop that asks for input, tests it agains the string, updates the results and starts over.  Your original was missing this loop that makes the game 'play'.